# an extension of an Olympiad problem

Tags: geometry, logic, solution-verification, contest-math

I'm a high school student and I'm currently working on my math extended essay. I chose an Olympiad question which is:

A piece of land of a square shape with dimensions 10m x 10m is divided into 100 square parcels with dimensions 1m x 1m. Initially, 9 of the parcels are overgrown by weed. If a parcel is surrounded by at least 2 parcels with weed from its sides after some time that parcel will be overgrown by weed. Can the whole piece of land grow into weed after some time?

I already have a rough idea on how to solve the original question, but my essay involves an extension to 3D, namely like this:

A space of land of a cube shape with dimensions 10m x 10m x 10m is divided into 1000 cubes with dimensions 1m x 1m x 1m. What is the minimum numbers of cubes to begin with so that the whole cube would grow into weed after some time, given that if a cube is surrounded by at least two other cubes with weed it will also be overgrown by weed?

After some thinking I have a hypothesis (which I have no idea whether it's correct or not). My approach start with 2D, for it is proven in the first part (somehow) that for a n x n square to grow into weed, n parcels are needed to begin with. Simplifying to a 3 x 3 x 3 cube, that means at least 3 cubes are needed for one side to be overgrown. Let the side be (x, y, z1). Now just a random cube in layer (x, y, z3) can lead to the whole cube being overgrown. I also made an expression for this:

c = n+z*, where z* means n/2 rounding backwards (for example 2.5 to 2) and c is the number of cubes needed. It's a bit messy but well.

The problem is, I don't know how to prove this hypothesis mathematically. The proving methods I learned like induction, direct proof etc. doesn't really apply here, which is why I'm stuck. Could you maybe point out some directions for me so that I can do some research and try proving it? Or, if it is impossible to prove, please also inform me so that I can change my plan. If it's solvable (which to me isn't right now), please don't post the solution because if so I would have to find another topic to do for my essay. I just want to know some proving methods which might be helpful in this case, thank you!

Comment: I will try and prove it myself when I will have spare time; however, from the look of it, your hypothesis could be proved by induction on n with some attention on trying to find counter-examples at each step. I am not completely sure of the truth of your hypothesis, therefore I advise you to find weaknesses and to rectify them if possible, otherwise, change hypothesis completely. Good luck for now!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too vague. I do have some advice. Before you move to three dimensions be sure you understand two. What does "surrounded by 2" mean? What happens if the 9 weedy parcels are all on the diagonal? When you have rigorously settled $m$ weedy parcels on an $n \time n$ field then it's time to move to three dimensions. There I suspect "surrounded by at least 2$ should be "surrounded by at least $k$" for some $k > 2$.

Comment: Surrounded by 2 means by two sides, so if 9 are arranged diagonally a 9 x 9 field would be covered. Thank you for your advice.@EthanBolker

Comment: Thank you! I'll try my best@MatteoMenghini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some hints:

Project the $n\times n\times n$ cubes into $n\times n$ squares, must the diagonal in the projection fully overgrown by weed? What does it tell us about the minimum number or overgrown cubes in the beginning?

In your example, projection of first layer and third layer overlap by exactly one square. Must the projection between consecutive odd layers overlap (answer is no, but in the even layer between them there must be ...)? What does it tell you about the number of cubes?

Comment: I'm not sure wether I got it correctly, but: originally, the projection's diagonal doesn't have to be overgrown. For example is a 3 x 3 square, (x1, y1), (x1, y3) and (x3, y2) would lead to the whole surface being overgrown. As for the second part, do you mean the projection of one whole overgrown layer and a square in the third layer, or just the projection of the starting situation? In the later case they don't necessarily overlap.

Comment: "Must the projection between consecutive odd layers overlap (answer is no, but in the even layer between them there must be ...)? What does it tell you about the number of cubes?" and I don't quite get it here, could you maybe explain a bit more?